# How do I loop through each line of a file and print out any words that contain two vowels next to each other?

Tags: python

This is what I tried. But I got an error message:

Error: <re.Match object; span=(74, 76), match='ai'>

The program should print out any words that contain two consecutive vowels.
Text.txt file content:

```
text = "This is a test file with a single word per line. Print any words that contain two vowels next to each other."   a = text.split(" ").rstrip("\n")  
my_file = open("test.txt", "w")
```

Python code:

```
   reg = r"[aeiou][aeiou]"
with open("text.txt") as f:
    for word in f:
        word = word.strip()
        print(re.search(reg, word, re.I))
```

Comment: Can you be more specific as to what "couldn't get the code to work" means?

Answer (score 0):

you can go through like this:

```
import re
with open('test.txt') as f:
  for line in f:
    line = line.strip()
    if re.search(r"[aeiou][aeiou]",line,re.I):
      print(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without a regex as well:

```
with open(ur_file) as f:
    for line in f:
        for x,y in zip(line,line[1:]):
            if all(e.lower() in 'aeiou' for e in (x,y)):
                print(line.rstrip())
                break
```

Answer (score 0):

Also:

```
import re
words = "This is a test file with a single word per line. Print any words that contain two vowels next to each other.".split()
print([w for w in words if re.match(r".*[aeiouy][aeiouy].*",w)])
```

Answer (score 0):

For a small number of words, you could create a list of all two-vowel pairs and check if any of them are in your target word. This reads a little cleaner than the other solutions, but is likely much less performant.

```py
def has_vowel_pair(word):
    vowels = 'aeiouy'
    vowel_pairs = {x+y for x in vowels for y in vowels} + {y+x for x in vowels for y in vowels}
    return any(pair in word for pair in vowel_pairs)
```